# Dependency injection injecting null when missing registration in Azure functions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I'm getting `null` injected into my constructor that has a dependency which I forgot to register.

In the below example dependency would be `null` when you forget to register `IDepencency` in the startup class

```
public class AzureFunction {
    public AzureFunction(IDepencency dependency) {

    }
}
```

I expected it to work the same as in .net core DI.

Is this expected behavior? And can I maybe change a setting to enable throwing exceptions?

**Edit:**

After reading HariHaran's answer, I realized it's only happening in a sub-dependency. This is a reproducible example:

```
public interface IClass1 { }

public class Class1 : IClass1
{
    private readonly IClass2 _class2;

    public Class1(IClass2 class2)
    {
        _class2 = class2; // This will be null
    }
}

public interface IClass2 { }

public class Class2 : IClass2 { }

public class Function1
{
    private readonly IClass1 _class1;
    public Function1(IClass1 class1)
    {
        _class1 = class1;
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,"post", Route = null)]
        HttpRequestMessage req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);

    }
}
```

And put this in the `functionsStartup`:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClass1, Class1>();
            //builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClass2, Class2>(); // Leave this commented
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In general a function usually gets all quote-unquote dependencies via its parameters. I understand that `function` and `azure-function` is not the same, but still having a cognitive dissonance that the usage of function needs some DI container

Comment: I can confirm I have the same issue, where dependency of a dependency is simply injected as null

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, I think it's because of the inner workings of the functions lib. That it uses `IServiceProvider.GetService` instead of `GetRequiredService`. But this is an assumption

Comment: this definitely feels like a bug in the DI resolution in azure functions

Comment: I posted a feature request to the MS Azure team about this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/41013373-enable-sub-dependency-injection-in-azure-functions

Comment: Thanks for the feature suggestion but this sounds like a different issue @ebug. It sounds like you just need to register Class2. I would like to have exceptions when I forget to register a class instead of having null injected.

Comment: You are right @Zenuka - thanks for that. I made a mistake in the order of my DI registrations (not part of the simplified example). When I corrected the order, Class2 is perfectly available in Class1. Feature request deleted :)

Comment: IIRC Azure Functions don't use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection as the DI container. They use a modified version of DryIoC.

Answer (score 1):

If the framework is not throwing the exception, then you can do it manually within the function's constructor.

For example

```cs
public class AzureFunction {
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public AzureFunction(IDepencency dependency) {
        _dependency = dependency ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dependency));
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No this is not the expected behaviour. The `func host` by default will throw

> Unable to resolve service for type 'FunctionApp2.IClass1' while attempting to activate 'FunctionApp2.Function1'.

Here's the simple reproducable piece of code.

```
public class Function1
{
    private readonly IClass1 _class1;
    public Function1(IClass1 class1)
    {
        _class1 = class1;
    }
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,"post", Route = null)]
        HttpRequestMessage req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);

    }
}
```

In the `functionsStartup` i commented my registration

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            //builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClass1, Class1>();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I just realized it only happens in a dependency of a dependency. See my updated question...